# Syntax error : operator expected (Closing parenthesis not handling)

Tags: ocaml

I have this error showing up when i tried to test my functions, would anyone know where this error came from ?

```
   let () =
            let t = Sys.time() in
            let args_n = Array.length Sys.argv - 1 in
            let args_list = Array.to_list (Array.sub Sys.argv 1 args_n) in
            List.iter (fun element ->
            let length_of_element = String.length element in
            let text = check_if_file(List.nth args_list 1) in
            let int_ls = search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element) (check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 )) in
            if (List.length int_ls)> 1 then print_string "pattern found at characters "
            else if (List.length int_ls) = 1 then print_string "Pattern found at character "
            else print_string "No patterns found."
            ;
            print_ls int_ls;
            Printf.printf "Execution time: %fs\n" (Sys.time() -. t);;
```

Ocaml is telling that it came from the closing parenthesis after length_of_element but the things is if i remove it, the open parenthesis at the List.iter line won't have any closing parenthesis matching with him.

```
let int_ls = search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element) (check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 )) in
```

Before trying to make this functions iterating on a list of string it was like that :

```
let () =
        let t = Sys.time() in
        let args_n = Array.length Sys.argv - 1 in
        let args_list = Array.to_list (Array.sub Sys.argv 1 args_n) in
        let pattern =check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 )in
        let lpattern = String.length pattern - 1 in
        let text = check_if_file(List.nth args_list 1) in
        let int_ls = search (to_list_ch pattern) text lpattern in
        if (List.length int_ls)> 1 then print_string "pattern found at characters "
        else if (List.length int_ls) = 1 then print_string "Pattern found at character "
        else print_string "No patterns found."
        ;
        print_ls int_ls;
        Printf.printf "Execution time: %fs\n" (Sys.time() -. t);;
```

But it was work only for one string and not multiple string, so i trie to iterate in a list to make it work not for only one string but a list of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `let x = e1 in e2` construct evaluates `e1`, and then makes its result available in `e2`. In your case, you have no `in e2`, so there is not much point in having `let x =`.

What you have written is `List.iter (fun -> ... let x = e1) in e2`. But what do you expect `x` to mean inside `e2`? Should it be the result of the first evaluation of `e1` in the loop? The last one? What if the body of the loop is never executed because the list you iterate over is empty? I suggest to step back and think a bit more about what you are actually trying to compute.

Comment: The functions always supossed that the list is not empty because in my use case it can't be empty. What i was trying to do was just passing into ``let int_ls = search (to_list_ch element) text length_of_element) (check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0 )) in`` the length_of_element and the element , through iterating in the (check_if_file(List.nth args_list 0)) given

Comment: This is just a part of code that is implementing the KMP algorithm in Ocaml and what i'm trying to do is making him work not for just a pattern but multiple patterns